# Text mode productivity tools

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, internet

Is there a curated set of tools for basic productivity that are text (as in console) mode only?

Example:

- web browsing -> lynx
- email/calendar/todo
- text editor -> vi
- facebook/twitter/reddit client
- news/weather/stocks

Comment: I've read many blog/magazine articles by writers who've tried to live for a whole month (or 28 days) using only terminal.   If it was looking for such a list, I'd have read one of those articles (they usually list a number, and strengths/weaknesses of each).  Some 'articles' maybe over 5 weeks (one article for each week & the summary is rather common).  Curated set - not that I'm aware of, but lists of favorite programs - many (usually created by writers/bloggers)  eg. https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/without-gui-how-live-entirely-terminal (but that's not the article I hoped to find..)

Comment: calendar  --> cal

Comment: calculator --> bc

Comment: print a pdf file -->  lpr

Comment: text editor --> vi, nano, emacs